# Active Record Association not saving in database

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have two models:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tools, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And I created a migration to provide the foreign key of the model:

```
class AddUserIdToTool < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tools, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for @tool, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @tool.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@tool.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tool from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @tool.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :tool_image %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I submit the form the foreign key is not updated(user_id). I see the following while in my console:

```
irb(main):002:0> Tool.last
  Tool Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tools".* FROM "tools"  ORDER BY "tools"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Tool id: 6, name: "wrench2", description: "another wrench", created_at: "2015-04-09 21:38:47", updated_at: "2015-04
-09 21:38:47", tool_image_file_name: "wrench.jpg", tool_image_content_type: "image/jpeg", tool_image_file_size: 3424, to
ol_image_updated_at: "2015-04-09 21:38:43", user_id: nil>
irb(main):003:0>
```

As you can see the `user_id` is `nil`

Here is my controller:

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :destroy, :edit, :update], notice: 'you must sign in first!'
  before_action :set_tool, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tools
  # GET /tools.json
  def index
    @tools = Tool.all
  end

  # GET /tools/1
  # GET /tools/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tools/new
  def new
    @tool = Tool.new
  end

  # GET /tools/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tools
  # POST /tools.json
  def create
    @tool = Tool.new(tool_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tool.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tool, notice: 'Tool was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tool }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tool.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tools/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tools/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tool.update(tool_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tool, notice: 'Tool was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tool }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tool.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tools/1
  # DELETE /tools/1.json
  def destroy
    @tool.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tools_url, notice: 'Tool was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_tool
      @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tool_params
      params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :description, :tool_image, :user_id)
    end

end
```

How would I get the user_id updated with the id of the logged in user? Do I have to include a hidden field in my form or something like that?

Also do I have to permit the user_id variable within my strong parameters in my controller? I have tried this but it has not solved the problem...

How does this work?

Comment: You has not included the most important part, the action in the controller where you actually process the form's submitted data.

Comment: @meagar I have updated my question with controller code. Hmm maybe I need to add some logic in my controller. something like: @user.tools.build(params[:user][:tool])

Comment: what is the convention in rails for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are building a tool on its own. To associate it with the user model you need to create a tool model in the following way:

`@user.tools.build`

It will create a new ActiveRecord tool model with proper user_id of a belonged model. But to get parent you need to fetch its id from your params. It could be done in a such way, in your action:

`@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`

Note: to make it possible your routes should be nested correspondingly (read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

So, all in all, your new action should look like:

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @tool = @user.tools.build
end
```

And in your routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :tools
end
```

Comment: what if I don't want my routes nested? Does that change what I am supposed to do? I cant find any information anywhere.

Comment: @coderwannabe2, basically you just need to know the user (or its id). Within the nested routes it is easy to fetch its id from params. But you can also enter it manually into the form. Then you wont need this line of code in your new action `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`. But instead you need to create a filed for user_id, and enter id of a user. Alternatively, you can use select field, to select from a list of existing users.

Comment: Can I do it with out creating a field? that seems like it is not an elegant solution... I am sure there must be a way this seems like such a  common use case.

Comment: @coderwannabe2 think about how your tool model knows to which of the users it should belong? There can be 1 or 100 or 1 000 000 users. Which of them should have that tool?

Comment: could you show me an example with code about what you mean? I think I am probably misunderstanding what you are saying. I don't want to have nested resources but can't figure out how to attach a tool to a the user that created without nesting or without a form_field.